# Kendo UI Grid - Sort by Descending Before Ascending

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've read through every online post I could find about about sorting with the Kendo Grid. Basically I'm trying to find a way to sort by descending first and then ascending after. I know how to set a default sort as descending when the grid loads, but I need this to happen any time a field is sorted. If there is no sort, it should sort by descending first.

```
  sortable: {
            allowUnsort: false
            SortByDescendingFirst: true <== Something like this
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's an option to define that - you can try something like this (this is for Q1 2014, in older versions you can do the same but you have to modify `kendo.ui.Sortable.fn._click` instead):

```
kendo.ui.Sorter.fn._click = function (originalFn) {
    return function (e) {
        var element = this.element,
            dir = element.attr(kendo.attr("dir"));

        if (!dir) element.attr(kendo.attr("dir"), "asc");
        if (dir === "desc") element.attr(kendo.attr("dir"), "");
        if (dir === "asc") element.attr(kendo.attr("dir"), "desc");

        originalFn.call(this, e);
    };
}(kendo.ui.Sorter.fn._click);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! This is really close although the sort stops working after I sort one field... Then sort a different field... Then sort the different field again the other direction. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: I would suggest these edits: kendo.ui.Sorter.fn._click = function (originalFn) {
    return function (e) {
        var element = this.element,
            dir = element.attr(kendo.attr("dir")),
            ariaSort = element.attr("aria-sort");
        
        if (!dir) {
            element.attr(kendo.attr("dir"), "asc")
            element.attr("aria-sort", "ascending");
        }

        originalFn.call(this, e);
    };
}(kendo.ui.Sorter.fn._click);

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is old but in case anyone lands here it would be helpful:

use initialDirection: "desc" as below property:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "id" },
    { field: "name" }
  ],
  sortable: {
    initialDirection: "desc"
  },
  dataSource: [ { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe" }, { id: 2, name: "John Doe" } ]
});
```

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/sortable.initialdirection